# Reflective factorization systems - from reflections to general adjunction?

Tags: ct.category-theory

In the context of Galois theory, the notions of "semi-left exact reflection" and "admissible *adjunction*" pop up. The notion of "simple reflection" is also crucial in simplifying theory by circumventing size conditions and simplifying factorizations.

Section 4 of the paper [*Reflective subcategories, localizations, and factorization systems*](http://journals.cambridge.org/download.php?file=%2FJAZ%2FJAZ1_38_03%2FS1446788700023624a.pdf&code=99c752c70c86fb397005a5003ed21b36) by Cassidy, Hébert, and Kelly characterizes simple reflections (Theorem 4.1) and semi-left-exact/admissible reflection (Theorem 4.3).

Looking at the proofs, it seems to me everything written holds for general adjunctions $F\dashv G$, not just reflections $r\dashv \iota$. Indeed it seems to me the role of reflections is prominent in Section 3 only because reflective subcategories of a fixed category are naturally ordered by inclusion, paving the way for a Galois connection with (pre)factorization systems (and even an interior operator!). Hence it seems reflections should only be relevant for bijective correspondence results, like Corollary 4.8.

Am I correct in saying Theorems 4.1, 4.3, and 4.5 hold for arbitrary adjunctions $F\dashv G$ rather than just reflections? If so, why does the section begin with "transcribing" to the case of reflections? If not, where am I wrong?

Comment: I can't see how to state thms 4.1, 4.3, 4.5 without $r\dashv i$ being a reflection. First of all $r$ must be a pointed functor; and even assuming it, you can't define a functor $\Phi$ sending the domain of $i$ into some pair $(E,M)$ of classes of arrows having some interesting property. Indeed, it's only when $i : B\to C$ is the inclusion of a reflective subcategory that $B\cong C[i(B)^{-1}]$, and $(\hom B)^\perp = $ arrows inverted by $r$.

Comment: @FoscoLoregian how about the following: Given $F\dashv G$ with $F:\mathsf C\to \mathsf B$, define $\Phi(F\dashv G)$ to be the prefactorization system fibrantly generated by the image of $G$ in $\mathsf C$. Since $Ff\perp g\iff g\perp Gg$, it still holds that $\mathcal L$ is the class of arrows inverted by $F$, where $(\mathcal L,\mathcal R)=\Phi (F\dashv G)$.

Comment: @FoscoLoregian ah, I think reflections are needed to ensure the unit is always inverted by the left adjoint, since without this, Theorem 4.1 simply isn't true.

Comment: Yes, that's a consequence of $i$ being a f.f. functor.

Comment: @FoscoLoregian yes, but you agree $\Phi$ is definable for any adjunction and the left class is always the class of arrows inverted by the left adjoint?